# JavaFX and MacOS Mouse

Tags: macos, javafx, mouse

When I change the window whith the mouse in my application, usually crashes, but only when I use OSX, in windows it works correctly, and when I use the keyboard it works good too. To change I use:

```
public void changeWindow(String window, String title) {
    Scene oldScene = menuBar.getScene();
    Stage stage = (Stage) oldScene.getWindow();
    Parent root;
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(window + ".fxml"));
        Scene scene;
            scene = new Scene(root, oldScene.getWidth(), oldScene.getHeight());

        stage.setTitle(title + " - Company Name S.L.");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.print.out(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?
-Thank you

Comment: What is the exception thrown when you use OS X?

Comment: This is the error. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VQ6IwNCnhs9nXS3k7YGtFhkGKDahT3ddfwKbsjpcCwc/edit

Comment: That is quite the error. The problem appears to be with the code that interfaces java with OS X. Unfortunately, I do not know what could be causing it. The only advice I have right now is to tweak your code slightly to see if the error persists. Try hard coding a new window to appear.

Comment: I've seen that it only crashes when I select an item from MenuItem, if I press a button it works correctly

Comment: It's hard to say why this is. Have you seen any other users experiencing similar issues? That might indicate it is a big rather than an error in your program's logic.

Comment: I've tried to create a simple program with only two windows, one with a button who changes to other, and the other with a MenuItem with 3 options, the first changes to the first window, the second don't do anything and the third closes the application. When I use the first option it crashes too. In the next comment I'll put the code

Comment: public void change() {
  Scene oldScene = menuButton.getScene();
  Stage stage = (Stage) oldScene.getWindow();
  Parent root;
  try {
   root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("prova.fxml"));
   Scene scene = new Scene(root, oldScene.getWidth(), oldScene.getHeight());
   stage.setScene(scene);
   stage.show();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
 }